# JQuery/JSONP/PHP - Firefox OK, but it doesn't work on Chrome and Opera

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, jsonp

I have to create a web application using JQuery and PHP with cross-domain AJAX requests. So, I use JSONP to do my request. It works fine on Firefox, but not on Chrome and Opera.

I have one function for executing the request :

```
function update()
{
    $.ajax({
        url : url,
        type : "GET",
        dataType: "jsonp",
        crossDomain : true,
        jsonpCallback : "updateCallback",
        async : false, 
        data : {'session_id' : sessionID,'user' : userName },
        error : function (xhr, status, error) {
            alert("Erreur de chargement du fichier '"+url+"' : "+xhr.responseText+" ("+status+" - "+error+")");
        },
        success: function(){
            alert("Success !");
        }
    });
}
```

This the callback function :

```
function updateCallback(data)
{     
    var i = 0;
    var messages = data.messages;

    while(i < data.messages.length){  
       appendMessage(data.messages[i]);
       i++;
    }

    saveLastMsgID = lastMsgID;
    doUpdate = updateInProgress = false;
}
```

The PHP script called by the AJAX request :

```
<?php

/* ... */ 

function sendResponse($messages,$date)
{
    header('content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8'); 
    header("Access-control-allow-origin: *");
    header ("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: x-requested-with", true);
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET,OPTIONS');

    $datas = array();

    for($i = 0 ; $i < count($messages) ; $i++){
        $msg = $messages[$i];
        $message = null;
        $message->sender = $msg->getSender();
        $message->date = $date;
        $message->msg = stripslashes($msg->getContent());
        $message->carrier = $carrier;
        $datas[] = $message;
    }
    $data->messages = $datas;
    echo $_GET['callback']. '('. json_encode($data) . ')'; 
}
?>
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Why all the CORS headers if you're using JSON-P?

Comment: @Quentin, amen. K-I-S-S. Scratch all that header goop.

Comment: I have removed all the header (I only kept : header('content-type: application/javascript; charset=utf-8');) and it's change nothing :s

Answer (score 3):

Man, you've got alot of stuff in there. It's not really necessary. Try this. It lets jQuery handle your callback so the success function gets passed the object represented by the JSON embedded in the response:

```
function update()
{
    $.ajax({
        url : url,
        dataType: "jsonp",
        // async : false, <-------- THIS IS IGNORED BY JQUERY DUE TO JSONP DATATYPE
        data : {'session_id' : sessionID,'user' : userName },
        success: function(data){
            // alert("Success !");
            var i = 0;
            var messages = data.messages;

            while(i < data.messages.length){  
               appendMessage(data.messages[i]);
               i++;
            }

            saveLastMsgID = lastMsgID;
            doUpdate = updateInProgress = false;
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: @adeneo, Good catch. I'll remove that, too. :)

Answer (score 2):

JSON-P isn't JSON. It is JSON embedded in a JavaScript program. The MIME type should be `application/javascript`.

It is possible that Chrome and Opera are reacting to what appears to be an attempt to inject a function call into a JSON string.

Answer (score 2):

I was wondering if you install any adblock plugins in your browser and your request url contained some keywords like "ad".

I had the similar issue, finally found it was the adblock caused the problem.